# Are these torques correct for a simple balancing/fulcrum experiment?

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, equilibrium

For my physics lab, they had us do a simple static equilibrium experiment where we rested a ruler on a fulcrum (at its center of mass) and then attached varying amounts of weight on either end at different distances from the fulcrum. This screenshot is the data we recorded (F1 is the weight of Mass 1 in Newtons, and the same for F2):

[image]

I believe the torque is supposed to be calculated by multiplying the magnitude of the force by the distance from the fulcrum, correct? And if that's right, then shouldn't the two torques cancel out since the ruler was balanced when the weights were added to it? Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you include the weight of the mass hangers? That's something students often overlook.  Something is obviously wrong with your data or your procedure.